# Is it possible to display gmail add-on cards at Inbox or must the user click on a message?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Id like to display a "Home" card if the add-on is opened at inbox, rather than the "Open an Email - Select an email for XYZ to recommend content for you" message. Universal Actions are not quite the same as they're hidden behind the menu icon.

I've been unable to find any examples or code of add-ons that achieves this, is it possible? any help much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail Add-on trigger criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843209/gmail-add-on-trigger-criteria)

Comment: Duplicate -
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028654/how-to-load-gmail-addon-without-opening-mail-message/54048571#54048571](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028654/how-to-load-gmail-addon-without-opening-mail-message/54048571#54048571)

Answer (score 0):

## Gmail Addons

- [Accessing Gmail Addons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/accessing-addons)